# Crank-Nicolson method for a couple PDE preserves the norm

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to show that, for this system :

$$\begin{cases}\frac{dv}{dt} = -w \\
\frac{dw}{dt} = v \\
u(0)=u_0 \end{cases}$$

and given $$u(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
v_{n}(t) \\ w_{n}(t)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

the Crank-Nicolson method preserves the norm i.e. $|u_{n+1}| = |u_n|$ $ \forall n$.

The CN method is given by $u_{n+1} = u_n + \frac{h_n}{2} (f(t_{n},u_{n}) + f(t_{n+1},u_{n+1}))$ and here is the problem I am facing :

I am taking the squared norm of both sides :

$$|u_{n+1}(t)|^2 = |u_n(t)|^2 + \frac{h_n^2}{4}|u_{n}(t)|^2 + \frac{h_n^2}{4}|u_{n+1}(t)|^2 $$

Since $f(t_{n},u_{n})=\begin{pmatrix}
-w_{n}(t) \\ v_{n}(t)
\end{pmatrix}$, we have that $|f(t_{n},u_{n})|^2=\begin{vmatrix}
-w_{n}(t) \\ v_{n}(t)
\end{vmatrix}^2 = \begin{vmatrix}
v_{n}(t) \\ w_{n}(t)
\end{vmatrix}^2=|u_n(t)|^2$

I end up with

$$|u_{n+1}(t)|^2(1-\frac{h_n^2}{4}) = |u_n(t)|^2(1 + \frac{h_n^2}{4}) $$

and the condition I am trying to prove is true only true when $h_n=0$

Could anyone point me where I made a mistake please ?

Comment: How are you "taking the squared norm of both sides", are all the vectors orthogonal so that Pythagoras applies?

Comment: @LutzLehmann No, I am just taking the euclidean norm of the vector $u(t)$ and square it to avoid square roots on both sides

Comment: Then this is wrong. You should also get some scalar products on the right side. It would be better to separate $u_n$ and $u_{n+1}$ before taking the norm square.

Comment: @LutzLehmann But I don't understand why I cannot take the norm of this vector, why would they need to be orthogonal ? I can take the squared norm of $a=(3,4)$ without this condition

Comment: It is what you do afterwards with the norm squares that is wrong. $\|u+v\|^2=\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2+2(u,v)$, and the scalar product only vanishes if the vectors are orthogonal.

Comment: Thanks @LutzLehmann, that helped a lot and solved my problem